# last modified date of directory

Tags: php, date

Is there any way to get the last modified date of a directory, including sub directories? either via shell script or php?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you after: the last time a file was added or removed from the directory tree? Or the last time a file in the directory tree was modified? Try to explain what you want as precisely as you can, give examples if necessary.

Comment: @Gilles:  the last time any file in a directory tree has been modified is what I'm after.  the single most recently modified date/time from inside the directory tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shell solution that assumes Linux (or more generally GNU find). For simplicity's sake, file names containing newlines are not supported.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -printf '%T@:%p\n' |
sort -t : -k 1 -nr |
head -n 1 |
sed -e 's/^[^:]*://'
```

Quick explanation:
  • List all the regular files in the tree; for each file, print its modification time, a colon and the name.
  • Sort by decreasing leading number.
  • Keep only the first line.
  • Strip the leading number and `:`.

Answer (score 1):

The Unix "stat" command will provide this info, as well as the PHP function by the same name.

Comment: find -type d | xargs stat --printf='Dir:%n\tModified:%y\n'  should do the trick; uses the stat command with a list of DIR's from find.

Answer (score 0):

i 'm not sure what you are asking, but have you tried `ls -la ?`

or even ...  find ./ -exec ls -lah  {} \; to see the last date of everything.

(It can be deployed in *nix systems)

Comment: see my comment @Gilles on the original question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to see a list of all directories/subdirectories (and not any files) in a location sorted by (and showing) their last modified date, you can use the following command:

`ls -lRt | grep ^d`

**Update:** You could take it a step further and limit the output to just the last modified date and name of the directory by using

`ls -lRt | grep ^d | awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8, $9}'`

The only problem with either of these listings is that you don't get a full path for each directory, so it can be difficult to tell what directories are subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

A shell script sounds like it might complicate this more then having to, however forgive me if I am not fully understanding the question.

tree would be the command I would use for this

syntax
tree -dfsD